# How does Authorization Code flow remember the user after local state is cleared?

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-ad-msal, msal.js, pkce

Given an app using Oauth 2.0 [Authorization Code Flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1) via Microsoft's [msal.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js), I login by providing my credentials.  Then I fully clear my browser's state, cache, local/session storage, and refresh the page so that the single page application doesn't know I'm logged in, but I'm still logged in with the Microsoft backend.

When I initiate another login, it is able to do so silently, without re-asking me for my credentials.

Apparently, via a request to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/redacted/oauth2/v2.0/token`, **the Microsoft backend can authenticate me as the same user even though I cleared the js memory and all cache/session/local storage**

How does this request get a valid [code](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.3) / [code_verifier](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636#section-4.5) to send to the Authorization Server in order to get an Access Token back for a user without re-entering credentials?

---

More details:

The following **does** require me to re-enter my credentials (as I would expect it to):

- a private/incognito tab
- closing the browser and reopening it
- using a different browser on the same computer

The following does **not** require me to re-enter my credentials and can log on silently:

- authenticating in a new tab with cleared local state
- authenticating in a new window of the same browser with cleared local state
- refreshing the tab and clearing local state

I would expect the 3 "not" scenarios to require credentials, but they do not.  How can I be authenticated without the browser keeping any local state?

Comment: note: MSAL [logout docs](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/logout.md)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Microsoft library was storing a cookie owned by AAD, not my app.
[answer on github](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/2797#issuecomment-749127961)